# Adjusting frequency of x-axis tickmarks in ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to increase the frequency of x-axis tickmarks in the `ggsurvplot` function from the package `ggplot2` in R 3.5.1 using the argument `xticks.by`. But no matter what I input the tickmarks frequency stays the same. Adjusting y-axis tickmarks with the `yticks.by` argument seems to work.

Example code:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

data(ovarian)
data.frame(ovarian)

surv_object <- Surv(time = ovarian$futime, event = ovarian$fustat)
fit1 <- survfit(surv_object ~ rx, data = ovarian)
ggsurvplot(fit1, data = ovarian, xticks.by = 150)
```

Runnig this code gives the following plot witht he default x-axis tickmarks (300):
[Survival plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg9oB.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use break.time.by

```
ggsurvplot(fit1, data = ovarian, break.time.by = 150)
```

Comment: Your welcome, luckily I used ggplot recently in a paper that will be published in two days.